# Effect of batch size on Input Dimension of maximum pooling layer?

Tags: tensorflow

In the following code batch size is 10 ,input channel are 2 and output channels are 32. I know that the output of the convolution act as input of maximum pooling layer whose output act as the input of fully connected layer. According to my understanding image height*image width*output channels (2*2*32) act as the input of maximum pooling layer. Means 32 images of size 2 by 2. But there are 10 images in input layer. Does input of max pooling will be 10*2*2*32?

```
input = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([10,4,4,2]))
filter = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2,2,1,32]))
result = tf.nn.conv2d(input, filter, strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
```

Answer (score 0):

The input will be 2x2, it will do it for the 32 feature maps ("images"), so the depth will be the same (32). The batch size means that it will do this operation for the whole batch (10).

So, you could be tempted to say 10*2*2*32, but the true is that the max pool operation is happening just in the 2*2 feature map.